# How to properly get user profile data from API in next-auth callbacks to append it to the session data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jwt, next.js13, next-auth

I have a Next.js 13 project using the app router.

I'm trying to implement next-auth to my application like this:

```js
import { APIFactory, AuthAPI } from "@/api";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "jsmith@example.com",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials) return null;

        const loginData = await AuthAPI.emailLogin({
          email: credentials.email as string,
          password: credentials.password as string,
        });

        if (loginData) {
          return {
            id: loginData.userId,
            access_token: loginData.access_token,
          };
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.access_token = user.access_token;
        token.userId = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.access_token = token.access_token as string;
      session.userId = token.userId as string;
      const UserAPI = APIFactory.createBaseUsersAPI(
        token.access_token as string
      );
      if (token.userId)
        session.profile = await UserAPI.fetchUserProfileById(
          token.userId as string
        );

      return session;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

From this code, the important part is where I call the `UserAPI.fetchUserProfileById`, that is the endpoint I use to fetch the profile data.

While testing, I place a console log inside my endpoint call and it's being called 3 times, I'm not sure why exactly 3 times but I see 3 console logs.

I don't like this, it should only call the API once, if possible, only once per login but it's being called at every page render.

My knowledge of next-auth it's pretty limited so I don't know even if this is the appropiate way to add more custom data to the session using this library.

More precisely, I need to know:

- If is this the correct way to fetch the profile data from an endpoint and place it inside the session data.
- Why is it being called multiple times and how could I get to call the auth endpoint only once per login.

Thank you.